# Создание дополнительных форм

Tags: php, javascript

Как сделать создание доп.форм для заполнения пользователями и все это дело записать в базу?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  function forma() 
  { 
  var div = document.getElementById('Result'); 
 div.style.display = (div.style.display == 'none') ? '' : 'none'; 
 div.innerHTML = '<?echo '<b>Ф.И.О./Ник:</b> <input type=text name=name size=50 value=""/>';?>'; 
  } 
 </script>

 echo '<a href onclick="forma(); return false;">Добавить игрока/команду</a>'; 
 echo '<div id="Result" style="display: none"></div>';
```

Так создается только одна форма.

Comment: Спасибо, так работает.
Теперь второй вопрос: как это все дело записать в БД? Ведь записывается только содержимое последней формы.

Comment: Еслт несколько полей имеют одинаковы ключ **name**, то передавайте массивом:

    <input type="text" name="name[]" value="" />

Comment: Одного массива мало. В базу пишется Array и все.

Comment: Можешь написать весь код?

Comment: Надо вашу задачу знать. Вам для каждого значения поля надо создать отдельную запись в БД? Или все записи надо хранить в одной строке?

Comment: mysql_query("INSERT INTO `player_comands` SET `id_user` = '".$user['id']."', `id_comands` = '".$fidd."', `name` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($name)."'"); 
Запись в БД имеет такой вид.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если на чистом JS, то можно так:

```
<script>
function append(id) {
    var node = document.getElementById(id),
        newNode = document.createElement('div');
    newNode.innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="name" value="" />';
    node.appendChild(newNode);
    return newNode;
}  
</script>
<div id="test"></div>
<a href="" onclick="append('test'); return false;">CLICK</a>
```

Но с помощью jQuery эти манипуляции делаются проще

**UPD**

```
if(isset($_POST['name'])){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $user= $_POST['user'];
    $query = "INSERT INTO player_comands (id_user, name) VALUES ";
    for($i = 0; $i < count($name); $i++){
        $query .= "('$user[$i]', '$name[$i]'),";
    }
    $query = substr($query, 0, strlen($query)-1); // убираем лишнюю запятую
    $res = mysql_query($query);
}
```

Comment: Добавляю.
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `player_comands`
(`id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`id_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
`id_comands` int(11) NOT NULL,
`name` text NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT
CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

Comment: Ага... У вас поле **player_comands** с автоинкрементом. Значит его не надо указывать в запросе, а вместо него **id_user** . Подправил в дополнении.

Comment: Я в таблицу player_comands пишу имена игроков.
Создаем команду, пишем ее название в таблицу user_comands.
И тут же добавляем игроков в команду.
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `user_comands` SET `id_user` = '".$user['id']."', `namecomands` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($namecomands)."'");
$fidd=mysql_insert_id();
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `player_comands` SET `id_user` = '".$user['id']."', `id_comands` = '".$fidd."', `name` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($name)."'");

Comment: Как правильно сам цикл составить?

Comment: Ох... Я же в дополнении вам написал цикл, который обрабатывает массив из поля формы. У вас только значение **name** приходит? Тогда в цикле и используйте его, а остальные значения подставляйте исходя из первого запроса. И я не могу врубиться - в первом запросе в поле **id_user** что добавляете? Тех же пользователей, что и потом имена потом вносите?

Comment: Не заметил. А то сам составил цикл и через некоторое время сервер выдал 504 ошибку)

Comment: Только name

Comment: Кстати, если только один массив name обрабатываете, то можно использовать цикл foreach

P.S. Перед тем, как вносить в базу, выведите запрос на экран, посмотрите, правильно ли всё сгенерировалось